# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent query takes too long time to 'count'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 with MySQL 5.6.33

When I check the DB query by applying `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` , it returns as following:

```
array:14 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists (select * from `agents` where `products`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id`) and exists (select * from `productlocations` where `productlocations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `town_id` = ?) and exists (select * from `productagents` where `productagents`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `product_status_id` = ?)"
  "bindings" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "674"
        1 => "1"
  ]
  "time" => 22286.26
  ]

  1 => array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select * from `products` where exists (select * from `agents` where `products`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id`) and exists (select * from `productlocations` where `productlocations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `town_id` = ?) and exists (select * from `productagents` where `productagents`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `product_status_id` = ?) order by `id` desc limit 10 offset 0"
  "bindings" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "674"
        1 => "1"
  ]
  "time" => 38.4
  ]

  2 => array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select * from `agents` where `agents`.`id` in (?)"
  "bindings" => array:1 [▶]
  "time" => 0.58
]
```

As you can see the result, the "count" query has taken 22286ms to complete , but the same query of filtering data has took only 38.4ms. Where I need to look at to make faster this query? Need to change in the DB or Eloquent?

Edit:

```
explain 
select * from `products` where exists 
    (select * from `agents` where `products`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id`) 
and exists 
    (select * from `productlocations` where `productlocations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `town_id` = 674) 
and exists 
    (select * from `productagents` where `productagents`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `product_status_id` = 1) 
order by `id` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Followings are explain output and my tables indexes
[image]

Comment: Use `explain ` before the each query to profile (example `explain select count(*) as aggregate ....`). Check if all the columns have the same value, most likely they'll use different keys for the query.
Also, if you don't already have indexes, it could be a good idea to add an index for the columns used on the `where` statements.

Comment: You can try what @milz recommends. What I would like to share is, when doing all these doesn't works then we can change our DB structure. We must add a column into table for total counts. Laravel provides very nice short code for increments and decrements ''DB::table('products')->increment('totalsales');''  This way, query will be fast when you have large data.

Comment: @milz : I found the issue when I am going to update my question with result of explain and checked indexes. There were incorrectly join the agents table and products table also has agent_id column but it was not indexed.

Comment: I'm glad you've sorted that out! : )

Comment: just make sure you index the column(s) that related to other table columns

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. The column `agent_id` should be indexed in the `products` table

Answer (score 0):

use this query to count primary keys instead of * will keep you faster then *

```
select count(products.id) as aggregate from `products` as Products
INNER JOIN `agents` as Agent ON (Agent.id = Products.agent_id )
INNER JOIN productlocations as ProductLocations ON (ProductLocations.product_id = Products.id AND Agent .town_id = 674) 
INNER JOIN productagents as ProductAgents ON (ProductAgents.product_id = Products.id AND ProductAgents.product_status_id = "your input status Id")
```

Comment: `select count(*) as aggregate from `table` is how the Laravel 5.2 use to get the total count of result rows, framework it-self. I am not sure can/how it change to `count(id_column)`

Comment: use all() or direct DB::query() instead of EloquentModel->count() method in this situation, if its good for custom query then why go with framework's default statement,

Comment: Yes, I am using Product::with(array(....))->paginate($limit); In the result of this, there is 'count' index. This delay is in that query.

Comment: In Laravel you are using lazy load by with() method, the more queries the more time it will take in result, better go with scope type methods in model to get connectwith other table and use join, it will work like charm